# sql query to get multiple records in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi im working on a query to get 1row for each product but the problem is that there are multiple records with propertys of 1 product.

**TABLE PRODUCTS_DATA**

```
NAME :  DESC.  | ID|FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|
Row 1:PRODUCT1 | 1 | 200  | high |      |      | 
Row 2:PRODUCT1 | 2 |  10  |      | low  |      |
Row 3:PRODUCT1 | 3 |      |      |      | 10   |
```

now i would like the get a query which displays only one record with all those properties.

Row 1: `PRODUCT1|200|10|HIGH|LOW|10`

because

```
row 1 | id1 | field 1 contains length data
row 2 | id2 | field 1 contains amount data
```

how in the world is is possible to get an result like this?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. Maybe try using sqlfiddle.com to display your table or better laying out your current output and what you want outputting.

Comment: `Order by ID limit 1`??

Comment: And what column names you should have? In your sample output there's 2 columns with data from FIELD1 column - 200 and 10

Comment: Roman Pekar my 'because' was wrong i edited the body!

the problem is that

ROW 1 | ID 1| field 1 .. contains length data
ROW 2 | ID 2| field 1 .. contains Amount data

i want to display row1 id1 field1 and row2 id2 field1 on the same row

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a331a/2/0

i like to view field 1 row 1 and 2 on 1 single row one is 10 amount and one is 200 lenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will get your solution now dear...

```
   SELECT 
   SS.[DESC], 
   (SELECT '|' + US.FIELD1
    FROM XYZ US
    WHERE US.[DESC] = SS.[DESC]
    FOR XML PATH('')) [FIELD1],
    (SELECT '|' + US.FIELD2
    FROM XYZ US
    WHERE US.[DESC] = SS.[DESC]
    FOR XML PATH('')) [FIELD2],
    (SELECT '|' + US.FIELD3
    FROM XYZ US
    WHERE US.[DESC] = SS.[DESC]
    FOR XML PATH('')) [FIELD3],
    (SELECT '|' + US.FIELD4
    FROM XYZ US
    WHERE US.[DESC] = SS.[DESC]
    FOR XML PATH('')) [FIELD4]
FROM XYZ SS
GROUP BY SS.[DESC]
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful about the semantics of the two "field1" columns. You are showing both coming out in your example result. Presumably you could end up with data in each of the four fields for each row and therefore a very variable length result with duplicate column names, which seems broken to me. (Or you need to fix whatever is inserting the data to use a real primary key!)

Comment: well, the problem is that we cannot change the database table because its not our product, and the change would be to expansive to reprogram the database structure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this, suppose that PRODUCTS_DATA.PRODUCT_DESC column gives the product description (DESC.):

```
SELECT PRODUCT_DESC,MAX(FIELD1),MAX(FIELD2),MAX(FIELD3),MAX(FIELD4) FROM PRODUCTS_DATA
GROUP BY PRODUCT_DESC;
```